# APNS service not sending from hosted computer

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, sockets, pushsharp

I have a push sharp service i need to send notification from hosted computer, i try from normal computer and it send notification but when i run on hosted computer and try to send it gives the exception below:

`System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> PushSharp.Apple.ApnsNotificationException: Apns notification error: 'ConnectionError' ---> PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnectionException: Failed to Connect, check your firewall settings! ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 17.188.167.200:2195
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.<connect>d__1c.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsConnection.cs:line 329
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.<connect>d__1c.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsConnection.cs:line 374
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.<SendBatch>d__7.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsConnection.cs:line 143
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsServiceConnection.<Send>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsServiceConnection.cs:line 49
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) PushSharp.Apple.ApnsNotificationException: Apns notification error: 'ConnectionError' ---> PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnectionException: Failed to Connect, check your firewall settings! ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 17.188.167.200:2195
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.<connect>d__1c.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsConnection.cs:line 329
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.<connect>d__1c.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsConnection.cs:line 374
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.<SendBatch>d__7.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsConnection.cs:line 143
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsServiceConnection.<Send>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsServiceConnection.cs:line 49<---
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> PushSharp.Apple.ApnsNotificationException: Apns notification error: 'ConnectionError' ---> PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnectionException: Failed to Connect, check your firewall settings! ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 17.188.167.200:2195
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.<connect>d__1c.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsConnection.cs:line 329
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.<connect>d__1c.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsConnection.cs:line 374
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.<SendBatch>d__7.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsConnection.cs:line 143
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsServiceConnection.<Send>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsServiceConnection.cs:line 49
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) PushSharp.Apple.ApnsNotificationException: Apns notification error: 'ConnectionError' ---> PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnectionException: Failed to Connect, check your firewall settings! ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 17.188.167.200:2195
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.<connect>d__1c.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsConnection.cs:line 329
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.<connect>d__1c.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsConnection.cs:line 374
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.<SendBatch>d__7.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsConnection.cs:line 143
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsServiceConnection.<Send>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\D\visualStudioProjects\PushSharp-masterMowazi\PushSharp-master\PushSharp.Apple\ApnsServiceConnection.cs:line 49<---`

so i disable the firewall to check but same problem, also i have opened the port below: 2195,2196,443,5223 with ip address range 17.0.0.0 -> 17.255.255.254 but also same problem .. any idea?